# checking if the name is valid

Tags: php, mysqli

So i'm trying to create a form that will allow people that have their name inputed like Name_Lastname register. But its not working, im using 2 input fields for name

Name:
Lastname:

and then i use sprintf to mix these two into Name_Lastname, and that works great, but then when i want to check if an entered name has invalid characters checking function doesn't work, even if my name is correct it shows it is not.

The function should forbid registering if user has anything but first of first name and last name capital, and _, example: Joan_Mackey = Valid

```
joan_Mackey = invalid
joan0_Mackey = invalid
Joan92_Mackey = invalid
```

but its not working, here is the code

```
   if(isset($_POST['register_button']))
    {       

        $name = clear($_POST['firstname']);
        $lastname = clear($_POST['lastname']);

        $createdname = sprintf("%s_%s", $name, $lastname);

        $ime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $createdname);

        $email = clear($_POST['email']);
        $pass = clear($_POST['password']);
        $cpass = clear($_POST['confpassword']);


        // Proveravanje ako ima _ i tih sranja
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Igraci WHERE Ime = '$ime'";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $ime);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if(preg_match("([A-Z]{1,1})[a-z]{2,9}+_([A-Z]{1,1})[a-z]{2,9}", $createdname))
        {
            if($row) // Ime nije registrovano kod dole
            {
                echo "Uneseno ime: '$ime' ";
            }
            else // Ime je vec registrovano, kod dole
            {
                echo "Uneseno ime: '$ime' ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "format imena nije validan.";
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you're suffering from cargo-cult programming. why are you using parameter binding when you have **NO** placeholders in your query in the first place? and if you're using prepared statements with parameter binding, why are you manually escaping the values?

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: what is the other way to escape the values ? i only know for real escape

Comment: `John O'Brien`, `Helen Hayes-Thomas` `Bernard de Maupassant`, `Ernst van Helsing`

Comment: Oh i know that, but this is for a game in which players have to use simulated(imaginated) name to register, John_Doe for example.
This has no relations with real names :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change

```
if(preg_match("([A-Z]{1,1})[a-z]{2,9}+_([A-Z]{1,1})[a-z]{2,9}", $createdname))
```

to

```
if(preg_match("^[A-Z][a-z]{2,9}_[A-Z][a-z]{2,9}$", $createdname))
```

This would allow user names to be build by using a first name of 3 to 9 chars and a lastname of 3 to 9 chars with proper capitalization.

Explanation:

```
^ = Start at beginning of string
[A-Z] = One capital letter
[a-z]{2,9} = two to nine small letters
_ = one underscore
[A-Z] = One capital letter 
[a-z]{2,9} = two to nine small letters
$ = Match must go up to end of string
```

Comment: Nope, not working, i enter name correctly but still showing that its not correct
http://i.imgur.com/aG9u4U8.jpg

Comment: EDIT: I think i got it now, please check if you can for me:

`code` if(preg_match("/^([A-Z]{1,1})[a-z]{2,9}+_([A-Z]{1,1})[a-z]{2,9}$/",$createdname))

Comment: Right, added "^...$" to regex.

Comment: You dont need `[A-Z]{1,1}`. It just defines that there should be at least on char and at most one char which is equivalent to `[A-Z]`